# How to read '\n' into variable with Bash's built-in command?

Tags: bash, readline, newlines

Somehow I'm not able to `read` the trailing `\n` sign into the `REPLY` variable. Under any circumstances I want to avoid a blank line that results from the `\n` being echoed by `read` but `echo` one in case of another character. Given:

```
declare -l REPLY
read >&2 -r -N 1 -p "Acknowledged? (y):" REPLY
if [[ "$REPLY" != $'\n' ]]; then
  echo >&2
fi
```

For me a possible workaround is it to make `read` to suppress (`-s`) echoing the input. But ideally the user should see the single character he input after the prompt.

Also `IFS= read -d''` doesn't get me the `\n` character into the variable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, your code works for me.

```
$ echo | bash -c 'read -rN1; echo "$BASH_VERSION <$REPLY>"'
4.2.36(1)-release <
>
```

With `-N`, no need to set `IFS`, and NL does end up in $REPLY. An empty `$REPLY` would only mean NUL (`<Ctrl-Space>`) or EOF or an error (exit status would be non-zero though for those two)

Answer (score 0):

Read uses `\n` as its record separator, so it will never be in `$REPLY`. The newline you are seeing is as a result of `echo`. If you're wanting to check for *only* a newline on one line (ie. a blank line), one of these tests will work:

```
[[ $REPLY == "" ]] # true if line is empty
(( ${#REPLY} )) # true if line is not empty
```

Note that since you don't invoke `read` with `IFS=`, this will also match input that consists solely of whitespace.

Comment: I tried with `IFS=` and `-d''` but no luck.

Comment: @TimFriske You need to use `-d ''` rather than `-d''`, otherwise read will think you're passing no arguments to `-d`. What are you hoping to achieve by reading the actual newline, though?

Answer (score 0):

As Chris mentioned, it's a separator, however to check the string length, you would do the following:

```
if [ -z "$REPLY" -o "$REPLY" == "y" ]; then
    echo "It was acknowledged"
else
    echo "Not acknowledged"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: This will break if `$REPLY` contains any whitespace, it needs to be quoted appropriately.

Comment: Quote the variable; there's no need to quote `y`.

Comment: It would also break for some values of `$REPLY` like `=` or '('... Don't use `-o`, use two `[` commands separated by `&&` and don't forget to quote your variables (and use `=` instead of `==`).